# Underscore.js perform operation on an object, not an array

Tags: underscore.js, javascript

Hey I'm new to [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and I'm trying to figure out how to perform an operation on a map. I read through the API and I'm afraid I'm missing something.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
doubled = _.someFunction( { bob: 25, sally: 30, tom: 5 }
                          , function(value){ return value*2; } 
                        );
```

Returning:

```
{ bob: 50, sally: 60, tom: 10 }
```

Any idea how to do this? Should I create a new function with `_.mixin()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Underscore indeed does not provide a `map` function for objects. (You can use [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) on objects, but it will return an array)

So, you will have to do it manually:

```
_.someFunction = function(o, f) {
    var res = {};
    for (var p in o)
        res[p] = f(o[p]);
    return res;
};
```

Of course you might use some iteration functions from underscore. Without a helper function, these snippets might be more or less expressive:

```
var doubled = {};
_.each({ bob: 25, sally: 30, tom: 5 }, function(p, value){
    doubled[p] = value*2;
});
```

```
var doubled = _.reduce({ bob: 25, sally: 30, tom: 5 }, function(m, value, p){
    m[p] = value*2;
    return m;
}, {});
```

```
var obj = { bob: 25, sally: 30, tom: 5 };
var doubled = _.object(
  _.keys(obj),
  _.map(_.values(obj), function(value){ return value*2; })
);
```

Comment: This was what I needed. See what I went went with below.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a double function like this:

```
function double(data) {

  var doubled = {};

  _.each(data, function(value, key) {
    doubled[key] = 2 * value;
  });

  return doubled;

};

double({ bob: 25, sally: 30, tom: 5 });
```

Comment: If I set `_.double = double` that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, here's what I ended up doing: (See the [reduce function API](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce))

```
_.mapValues = function( object, iterator, context ){
    if (context) iterator = _.bind(iterator, context);
    return _.reduce( 
          object
        , function( memo, value, key ){ 
                memo[key] = iterator( value, key ); 
                return memo; 
                }
        , {} )
};
```

Comment: `context`? Shouldn't it be `func.call(context, value, key)` then?

Comment: EDITED. I had to grab their source for that one. I copied the line of code they used.